# Confused by the syntax used to process the argument in a Python Generator

Tags: python-3.x, generator

In the function cache_gen, the argument is assigned to values as: values = source(), rather than values = source?
I realise they must be doing it to ensure that the argument becomes a generator but I have been unable to find any documentation to explain this syntax.
I just want to make sure I understand it properly.

```
import numpy as np

SAMPLER_CACHE = 10000

def cache_gen(source):
    values = source()
    while True:
        for value in values:
            yield value
        values = source()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    randn_gen = cache_gen(lambda: np.random.standard_normal(SAMPLER_CACHE))
```

Comment: Since in your example you pass a lambda (hence a function) to `cache_gen` it seems normal to me that `cache_gen` calls the function ie `source()` . Otherwise it would simply assign `values` to a function object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are passing in a lambda as a parameter. They are calling `source()` to get the output of the lambda, which itself is the output of `np.random.standard_normal(SAMPLER_CACHE)`. They are then using a generator to output all the values one at a time.